# How to represent a map of literal keys in RDF

Tags: rdf, owl, datamodel

How can I represent a map of literal keys in RDF? Similarly to how typed languages have `Map<string, any>`, I am looking for something like `rdf:Seq`, `rdf:Bag`, and `rdf:Alt` for maps (a.k.a dictionaries, associative arrays) that can hold a literal as the key.

Comment: with two properties `key` and `value` attached to a (blank) node I'd say - there is at least no native map structure in RDF. For example, `[:key "key1" ; :value 15] .` - or `[a :Entry; :key "key1" ; :value 15] .` or ...

Comment: RDF is not a programming language. Encoding programming structures like maps, arrays, etc. in RDF is as meaningful (or meaningless) as encoding them in a relational database. With that said, if you really want to encode maps with literal keys in RDF, AKSW's solution is spot on.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann well actually, RDF has some ordered and not ordered collections as mentioned in my question so I do not agree with your statement.

Comment: @AKSW your suggestion looks reasonable enough. Thank you